# Cannot add a managed .dll into a C# project

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, managed

I have a C++ library and to be used in C# solution I created a CLR project (managed). So, I had included the managed .dll in my desire C# project. The intellisense can see it, I can acces the classes from that library, but when I compile the code "The type or namespace name "XXXX" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
I've tried to clean and rebuild the project, to restart Visual Studio (2013), to remove it and add it again the reference and so on, but without success.

Thank you!

Comment: Hm I recall doing this from school.  But don't you need a middle-hand?  A wrapper reference class that works as a bridge between the native code and C#?  That class would call the native functions and could be used from C#.

Comment: Did you add it as a reference under `References`?

Comment: Usually this is because the library you are linking was compiled for 64 bit, while you are compiling for AnyCPU or 32-bit. Make sure the architectures of both projects match. However I will say that if you are trying to use an unmanaged DLL simply by including it in a managed C++ project and linking, you still need *something* to marshal across the managed/unmanaged code, its not just magic because you added the extra step.

Comment: @ Placeable, I already said that i create a managed project. That's my bridge between C++ and C#.

Comment: @Matthew Watson: Yes, it is included

Comment: @Ron Beyer - I had done your steps but without success. I saw that i can load the .dll file into a small project and it works, without being forced to compile both projects to x64 or Any CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem! It seems that the managed code was build on 4.5 framework and the project where I wanted to introduce the .dll was on 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

right-click the dll in project's referencies

choose properties

set "embed interop types" to false

Answer (score 0):

If your managed bridge calls some unmanaged code, you'll want to make sure that native (unmanaged) library is getting copied to the right subdirectories by Visual Studio.  The IDE will copy the managed bridge code around as expected (i.e. into the Release or Debug or whatever subdirectory) but it doesn't know enough about the linkage between your bridge code and the unmanaged code to also copy the unmanaged library to the right place.